# Looping through many different arrays of different dimension

Tags: fortran

I have a bunch of arrays of different length which are all something like `a1 = [1.0]`, `a2 = [1.0,2.0]`etc. I need to loop through all the arrays in a function and perform operations with their elements, but none of them are functions of an index. I was wondering what the best way of doing that in Fortran 95 would be? I think you could make an array of dimension `(max_length, max_length)`, and put them all in that; this would allow you to reference each element by an index, but it would waste space and you'd have to pass the function the entire array every time you call it, rather than just the individual arrays (I don't actually know if that matters, but it seems like it would.)

Comment: Why do you insist on Fortran 95 when you use Fortran 2003 array constructor syntax? Otherwise I would use array of pointers (using a derived type).

Comment: Why not simply using [lbound](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/LBOUND.html) and ubound for each array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really depends on the actual case you have. If the length of the various arrays are not the same, but at least in the same order of magnitude, you may be better with one single array for all of them. You would then need, however, an additional array which gives the number of elements for every array. You function could then look something like:

```
module test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)

contains

  subroutine process(array, nelems)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: array(:,:)
    integer, intent(in) :: nelems(:)

    integer :: ii, jj

    do ii = 1, size(arrays(dim=2))
      do jj = 1, nelems(ii)
        ! Do something with element jj of array ii.
      end do
    end do

  end subroutine process

end module test
```

where the subarray `array(1:nelems(ii),ii)` stores the elements of the i-th 1D array.

Following points are maybe interesting to note:

- You should arrange your 1D-subarrays in the collective 2D-array column wise, so that the subarrays are continuos in the memory.
- You have to pass only two arrays instead of a bunch of arrays to the subroutine. This should give a clearer code.
- Of course you waste some memory, as the shape of the collective array must be `(max_nr_of_elements_in_an_array, number_of_arrays)`. If the array lenghts are *very* different and you have really a lot of arrays, so that the wasted memory becomes significant, you could think about the array of arrays approach  [as suggested by Eudoardo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16500736/1859258). However, this is often slower as the direct approach since the individual arrays are scattered in the memory (problematic for caching).

Comment: Thanks, the arrays are all pretty small to I'm just going to make one big one. I also didn't know that arranging things in columns vs. rows mattered.

Answer (score 1):

Having an array of (maxlen, maxlen) will only cause trouble if you are talking about (thousands, thousands) otherwise it's just an inefficient approach.

Supposing your arrays are all of the same type and the same number of dimensions, then you could create a derived type which would hold your arrays and then create an array of the type you just created. Therefore you would have an array of variable lenth's array.

```
type arrays
    integer(kind=8):: length !optional but very helpfull
    integer(kind=8), dimension(:), allocatable:: a
end type arrays
```

now you can declare your array of type arrays:

```
type(arrays), dimension(:), allocatable:: arrayList
type(arrays):: arrayList ( 1000 )  !if you know beforehand how many arrays you need
```

There are two things to notice with this approach:

- in my experience, looping through arrays of derived types are slower than through native type arrays.
- now you access your a1, a2 as  `arrayList(i) % a(j)` which can be scary at first sight

Source: http://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys466/comp_info/derived.html

For aditional information, you could visit [Fortran Wiki](http://fortranwiki.org) which is a very nice source.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, not pure Fortran 2003, on which OP insists.